# SQL: Datepart not returning results for 1 of 7 weekdays

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble getting my datepart to work for day 7 (saturday) of the 7 weekdays. It's returning the proper results for Monday - Friday. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT 
        u.username AS poweruploader,
        u.profile_uploads_count AS uploads,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,i.submission::date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS sunday,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,i.submission::date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS monday,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,i.submission::date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS tuesday,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,i.submission::date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS wednesday,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,i.submission::date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS thursday,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,i.submission::date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS friday,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,i.submission::date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS saturday
    FROM application.users AS u
    JOIN application.image AS i ON u.username = i.username
    WHERE profile_uploads_count >= '5'
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Do you have any records that fit your WHERE criteria? Also, if that's an int field don't wrap `'5'` in quotes as SQL has to do a conversion.

Comment: `datepart` isn't a valid function in postgresql afaik. it should be date_part. The above query should throw an error. `weekday` isn't a valid sub-field for datetime types. it should be `'dow'`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Postgres, then the function is [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).  It returns values in the range 0 to 6, with 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday.

Comment: 'weekday' is not used either: use **dow**: e.g.  `date_part('dow',datecolumn)`  **or** `extract(dow from datecolumn)`